# Android studio says there is an error when I call a function that is lower down in the code in kotlin, do I have something set wrong

Tags: function, android-studio, kotlin

Android studio says there is an "Unresolved reference: connect" error when I call a function that is lower down in the code in kotlin, do I have something set wrong.  As long as the function is above the call it works but, I can't call a function lower in the code like it is a single pass compiler.  Below con=connect() causes an error but, I have an identical call where the code is below the function and that works fine.

```
    class MainActivity() : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val handler= Handler()


    private enum class UsbPermission {
        Unknown, Requested, Granted, Denied
    }
    lateinit var _usbManager: UsbManager
//    lateinit var device: UsbDevice
    //private val _context: Context = context
//    private var _errorMessage: String = ""
    private var _connected: Boolean = false
//    private var _deviceName: String = ""
//    private var _device: UsbDevice? = null
    private lateinit var _serial: UsbSerialPort
//    private var _receiveBuffer = Vector<Byte>()

    private val withIoManager = false

    private var broadcastReceiver: BroadcastReceiver? = null
//    private var mainLooper: Handler? = null
//    private val receiveText: TextView? = null
//    private val controlLines: ControlLines? = null

    private var usbIoManager: SerialInputOutputManager? = null
//    val device: UsbDevice? = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE)
//    private val usbSerialPort: UsbSerialPort? = null
    private var usbPermission: UsbPermission = UsbPermission.Unknown

    private val INTENT_ACTION_GRANT_USB = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".GRANT_USB"
//    private val WRITE_WAIT_MILLIS = 2000
//    private val READ_WAIT_MILLIS = 2000

//    private val ACTION_USB_PERMISSIONs = "com.android.example.USB_PERMISSION"
    val ACTION_USB_PERMISIION = "permission"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)

        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
        )
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        _usbManager = getSystemService(USB_SERVICE) as UsbManager
//        val deviceList = _usbManager.getDeviceList()
//        val device = deviceList.get("deviceName")

//        val permissionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, Intent(ACTION_USB_PERMISSIONs), 0)
//        _usbManager.requestPermission(device, permissionIntent)
        val filter = IntentFilter()
        filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED)
        filter.addAction(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_ATTACHED)
        filter.addAction(ACTION_USB_PERMISIION)
        registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter)
```

I have added the class decloration above which I got from the serial example program, maybe there is a problem in the way I defined this.

```
        val ctson = Runnable {
            if (con == true) {
                _serial.setRTS(true)
            }
        }

        val mListener: Listener =
            object : Listener {

                override fun onNewData(data: ByteArray) {
//                    mainLooper.post(() -> {
                    if (efitable == 1) {
                        for (i in 0 until data.size) table[len + i] = data[i] //fuel table
                        len = len + data.size
                        //                    _serial.setRTS(false)
                        //len = receive(387, 400)
                        if (len >= 8187) { // && efitable==1) {
                            _serial.setRTS(false)
                            efichk = 0
                            len = 0
                            for (i in 0 until 8184) efichk = efichk + (table[i].toInt() and 0xFF)
                            efichk = (efichk and 0xFFFF)
                            chktst =
                                (table[8185].toInt() and 0xFF shl 8 or (table[8184].toInt() and 0xFF)).toInt()
                            if (efichk == chktst) {
                                efitable = 2
                                etable(table) //extract data from table
                                _serial.write("R".toByteArray(), 4)
                                _serial.setRTS(true)
                                sergo = 0
                            } else {
                                efitable = 0
                                _serial.purgeHwBuffers(true, true)
                                _serial.write("R".toByteArray(), 4)
                                _serial.setRTS(true)
                                sergo = 0
                            }
                        }
                    } else { //if(efitable==0 || efitable==2){
                        for (i in 0 until data.size) rsdash[len + i] = data[i]
                        len = len + data.size
                        if (len >= 387) {  // && (efitable==0 || efitable==2)) {
                            _serial.setRTS(false)
                            len = 0
                            chksum = 0
                            for (i in 0 until 384) chksum = chksum + (rsdash[i].toInt() and 0xFF)
                            chksum = (chksum and 0xFFFF)
                            chktst =
                                (rsdash[385].toInt() and 0xFF shl 8 or (rsdash[384].toInt() and 0xFF)).toInt()
                            if (chksum == chktst) {
                                if (efitable == 0) {
                                    efitable = 1
                                    sergo = 20
                                    _serial.write("X".toByteArray(), 4) //88
                                    display(rsdash)
                                    _serial.setRTS(true)
                                } else {
                                    if (save == 2) {
                                        _serial.write("U".toByteArray(), 4) //85
                                        efichk = 0
                                        for (i in 0 until 8184) efichk =
                                            efichk + (table[i].toInt() and 0xFF)
                                        table[8184] = (efichk and 0xFF0000 shr 16).toByte()
                                        table[8185] = (efichk and 0xFF00 shr 8).toByte()
                                        table[8186] = (efichk and 0xFF).toByte()
                                        _serial.write(table, 1200) //85
                                        efichk = (efichk and 0xFFFF)
                                        save = 0
                                        _serial.setRTS(true)
                                    } else {
                                        _serial.write("R".toByteArray(), 4) //82
                                        if (exit > 1) {
                                            sergo = 1
                                            if (con == true) {
                                                _serial.setRTS(false)
                                                _serial.close()
                                                _connected = false
                                                con = false
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            display(rsdash)
                                            handler.postDelayed(ctson, 37)
                                            sergo = 0
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                _serial.write("R".toByteArray(), 4)
                                for (i in 0 until 100) Thread.sleep(1)
                                _serial.purgeHwBuffers(true, true)
                                _serial.setRTS(true)
                                _serial.purgeHwBuffers(true, true)
                            }
                        }
                    }
//                })
                }

                override fun onRunError(e: Exception) {
                    len = 0
                    if (con == true) {
                        _serial.setRTS(false)
                        _serial.close()
                        _connected = false
                        con = false
                        con = connect()  //This line causes the "Unresolved reference: connect" error
                    }
/*                   _serial.setRTS(false) // original code to try to recover serial port
                    _serial.write("R".toByteArray(), 4)
                    len = 0
                    for (i in 0 until 120) Thread.sleep(1)
                    _serial.purgeHwBuffers(true, true)
                    _serial.setRTS(true)
*/              



            }


        fun connect(): Boolean {
            val drivers = UsbSerialProber.getDefaultProber().findAllDrivers(_usbManager)
            if (drivers.isEmpty()) {
                return false
            }

            val driver = drivers[0]
            val _connection = _usbManager.openDevice(driver.device)
            if (_connection == null) {
                _connected = false
                return false
            }

            val port = driver.ports[0]
            if (port == null) {
                _connected = false
                return false
            }

            try {
                port.open(_connection)
                port.setParameters(
                    115200,
                    8,
                    UsbSerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
                    UsbSerialPort.PARITY_NONE
                )
                port.purgeHwBuffers(true, true)
                _serial = port
                _connected = true

//                if (withIoManager) {
//                    usbIoManager = SerialInputOutputManager(usbSerialPort)
//                    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(usbIoManager)
//                }
                //usbIoManager = SerialInputOutputManager(_serial,this)
                usbIoManager = SerialInputOutputManager(_serial, mListener)
                Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(usbIoManager)
//                val submit = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(usbIoManager)
//                Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher(usbIoManager)

                _serial.setRTS(true)
                return true

            } catch (e: IOException) {
                //e.printStackTrace()

                if(_connected==true){port.close()}
                _connected = false
                return false
            }
        }
//        mainLooper = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

        broadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
                if (intent.action == INTENT_ACTION_GRANT_USB) {
                    usbPermission = if (intent.getBooleanExtra(
                            UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED,
                            false
                        )
                    ) UsbPermission.Granted else UsbPermission.Denied
                    con=connect()
                }
            }
        }
        //mainLooper = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
```

Comment: And the error is...?

Comment: "Unresolved reference: connect" error

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Maybe you've put connect() outside of class that contains onRunError() or something like that.

Comment: From what I know (which might not be much) they are in the same class as I think I only have one "MainActivity"

Comment: The code is quite confusing and also its not the complete code of the activity. Can you post a version of the complete activity with all code inside methods removed? Then it would be much shorter and we can see the structure much better. Also - is the error shown when you build the app or directly in the editor? Are there any errors shown in the editor? I.e. is there a red exclamation mark in the top right corner of the editor window?)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your KotlinRuntime library is not attached to the project. Have a look under "Project Structure" If it is there, you can try to delete it an then run "Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin in Project"

Comment: I added more code, I checked "Project Structure" and it seems to be fine (I am new to Android Studio though).   Ran "Tools -> Kotlin -> Configure Kotlin in Project" and it said all modules are configured.